# datepicker for custom post type admin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hey guys im trying to get the jQuery datepicker working for the admin section for a custom post type. Essentially I just want a date and then the ability to store that date in the DB then query the DB to pick things like the month. For now I just want the datepicker ui to start working and then I can work on adding the data to the DB. So i first added a jquery stylesheet and the jqueryui script using the `admin_print_styles` and `admin_enqueue_scripts` respectively.

```
function admin_styles() {
    wp_register_style('jqueryuicss', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css', array('jquery-ui-styles'), '1.12.1');
    wp_enqueue_style('jqueryuicss');
 
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_styles');

function admin_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('jqueryui', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery-ui'), '1.12.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqueryui');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
```

I then added  the metabox to my custom post type.

```
function post_date_field() {
   echo '<input type="text" id="jquery-datepicker" name="entry_post_date" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'entry_post_date', true ) . '">';
}
function post_date_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box('entry_post_date', 'Date', 'post_date_field', 'events', 'side', 'default');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'post_date_meta_box');
```

I have a library function that attempts to call the `datepicker()` in a js library file:

```
    function datepicker(){
        jQuery('#jquery-datepicker').datepicker();
    };
```

The date metabox appears in the edit post section but the jqueryui styles and script dont seem to run at all. Any suggestions on how to get this going? Just to get the scripts and styles registered and enqueued and get the date picker to pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues I noticed in your code

- I don't see where/how you're calling that custom `datepicker()` function and you should use the same `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook for registering/enqueueing a stylesheet (`.css`) file.
- You should only load the CSS and JS files on the pages where the styles and scripts are being *used*, e.g. in your case, the post editing screen for your `events` post type, where the screen ID is `events` (the CPT slug).
- `$post` is not defined in your `post_date_field()` function — you should've used `function post_date_field( $post )`.

### Making the Datepicker works

1. First, enqueue the CSS and JS files.

   Note: I used the [Smoothness theme](https://code.jquery.com/ui/), but you can just choose whichever you like. I also used the jQuery UI Datepicker library that came [bundled in WordPress core](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress) where the script handle name is `jquery-ui-datepicker`.

   ```php
   function admin_styles() {
       if ( 'events' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
           wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-smoothness', // wrapped for brevity
               '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', [], null );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_styles' );

   function admin_scripts() {
       if ( 'events' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
           wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', // wrapped for brevity
               '/path/to/your-script.js', [ 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ] );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts' );
   ```
2. Then, apply the Datepicker widget to your custom field.

   Note: I don't use the custom `datepicker()` function. Instead, I called the Datepicker directly once the document is [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

   ```js
   // This code should be in your-script.js.

   jQuery( function ( $ ) {
       $( '#jquery-datepicker' ).datepicker();
   } );
   ```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this out ASAP

Comment: No problem, take your time.

Comment: This works as expected. The data is put into the field but for some reason it says I get an error saying `jQuery is not defined`. I also added `$post` to the `post_date_field`. It now looks like this: `function post_date_field($post) {
   echo '<input type="text" id="jquery-datepicker" name="entry_post_date" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'entry_post_date', true ) . '">';` I guess the next step is storing this in the DB

Comment: Yes, I believe so - you can use the [`save_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/). And sorry about that console error, I made a typo - I used `} )();`, but the correct one is just `} );`. :-)

Comment: Thanks again. Already figured that part out :D. Next step is breaking it down into different parts

Comment: I used `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'entry_post_date', strip_tags( $_POST['entry_post_date'] ) );` is this the best way to do it?

Comment: That's fine, but WordPress has a better version of `strip_tags()`: [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/). But anyway, we shouldn't discuss about it here - keep a question to one question. :)